# Поиск всех возможных комбинаций слов

Tags: delphi, комбинаторика

Всем доброго времени суток!
Подскажите, есть задача, найти все возможные комбинации слов из списка.
Например, из списка: арбуз, банан, слива, вишня нужно получить примерно следующее:

```
        арбуз
        арбуз - банан
        арбуз - банан - слива
        арбуз - банан - слива - вишня
        банан
        банан - арбуз
        банан - арбуз - слива
        банан - арбуз - слива -вишня
        ...
```

понимаю что количество комбинации будет расти в геометрической прогрессии с добавлением каждого нового элемента в список. Но нужны не все комбинации, они будут отфильтровываться. Главное условие, каждый элемент должен повторятся только один раз. И комбинации `банан - арбуз` и `арбуз - банан`, это разные комбинации. На этом форуме, один хороший человек подсказал код, который решает мою задачу, если представить элементы строкой:
Код:

```
procedure Generate(s, comb: string; idx: Integer);
var
  i, k: Integer;
  temp: string;
begin
  if idx > Length(s) then begin
    if Length(comb) > 0 then
      Writeln(comb);
    Exit;
  end;

  for k := 1 to Length(comb) + 1 do begin
    temp := comb;
    Insert(s[idx], temp, k);
    Generate(s, temp, idx + 1);
  end;
  Generate(s, comb, idx + 1);
end;

begin
  Generate('abc', '', 1);
  Readln;
end
```

Но при попытке переделать процедуру под список, столкнулся с ошибками. Вот пример моего кода:

Код:

```
procedure Generate(list, comb: TStringList; idx: integer);
var
  temp :  TStringList;
  i, k : integer;
begin
  temp                  := TStringList.Create;
  temp.Duplicates   := dupIgnore;
  temp.Sorted        := false;


  if idx >  list.Count-1 then
    begin
      if  comb.Count-1 > 0 then
        begin
          Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add(comb.Text);
        end;
    Exit;
  end;


  for k := 0 to comb.Count-1 do begin
    temp.Assign(comb);
    temp.Insert(k, list[idx]);
    Generate(list, temp, idx + 1);
  end;
  Generate(list, comb, idx + 1);

comb.Free;
end;
```

Ошибка "Invalid pointer operation".

Подскажите, где ошибся? Или, если есть, другой вариант решения задачи. Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось достаточно причесать ошибки индексации  и ввести модификацию-восстановление одного экземпляра списка

```
procedure GenerateList(list, comb: TStringList; idx: integer);
var
  k : integer;
begin
  if idx > list.Count-1 then begin
    if comb.Count > 0 then
      Writeln(comb.CommaText);
    Exit;
  end;

  for k := 0 to comb.Count do begin
    comb.Insert(k, list[idx]);
    GenerateList(list, comb, idx + 1);
    comb.Delete(k);
  end;
  GenerateList(list, comb, idx + 1);

end;

var
  sl, comb: TStringList;

begin
  sl := TStringList.Create;
  sl.CommaText := 'арбуз банан cлива';
  comb := TStringList.Create;
  GenerateList(sl, comb, 0);
  Readln;
  sl.Free;
  comb.Free;


cлива,банан,арбуз
банан,cлива,арбуз
банан,арбуз,cлива
банан,арбуз
cлива,арбуз,банан
арбуз,cлива,банан
арбуз,банан,cлива
арбуз,банан
cлива,арбуз
арбуз,cлива
арбуз
cлива,банан
банан,cлива
банан
cлива
```

Comment: ОГРОМНЕЙШЕЕ ВАМ СПАСИБО! Я Вам уже должен, как земля колхозу))